# socket messaging not working in android and Html

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I am implementing socket messaging app using nodejs server ,html and android client. So that, i have implemented the following ways,

**Step 1:** Create the server with the following code which works fine.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000,console.log("Socket.io Hello Wolrd server started!"));
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    //console.log("Client connected!");
    socket.on('chat_sample_test', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg.id);
        console.log(msg.message);
      socket.emit(msg.id, msg.message);
    })
});
```

**Step 2:** I have created HTML client app with the following code and it is connected with server and works perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io("http://192.168.1.138:3000");
    socket.on("computer", function(msg) {
        document.getElementById('server').innerHTML = msg;
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btnSend").click(function(){
        sendMsg();
      });
      $('#inptBox1').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
          sendMsg();
          return false;    //<---- Add this line
        }
       });
    });
    function sendMsg(){
          var message=$("#inptBox1").val();
          var messageObj={};
          messageObj.id="mobile";
          messageObj.message=message;
          socket.emit('chat_sample_test', messageObj);
    }

    </script>
    <p id="server" ></p>
    <p id="client"></p>
    <input type="text" id="inptBox1" placeholder="Enter msg">
    <button  id="btnSend">Send</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Step 3:** I have implemented Android client with the following code and it's also connected with server works fine.

**Custom Application class:**

```
public class ChatApplication extends Application {

        private Socket mSocket;
        {
            try {
                IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
                opts.forceNew = true;
                opts.reconnection = false;
                mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.138:3000");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        public Socket getSocket() {
            return mSocket;
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity Class:**

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;



    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import io.socket.client.Ack;
    import io.socket.client.Socket;
    import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        EditText messageBox;
        Button sendButton;
        ListView chatroom;
        ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
        List<ChatModel> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        private Socket mSocket;
        boolean isConnected;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ChatApplication app = (ChatApplication) getApplication();
            mSocket = app.getSocket();
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
            mSocket.on("mobile",onMessageReceive);

            mSocket.connect();
            init();

        }

        void init() {
            chatroom = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatroom);
            sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
            messageBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageBox);
            sendButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!isConnected) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            isConnected = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        private Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        isConnected = false;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mSocket.connect();
                    }
                });
            }
        };


        Emitter.Listener onMessageReceive = new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (args.length > 0) {
                            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                            String username="";
                            String message="";
                            try {
                                username = data.getString("username");
                                message = data.getString("message");
                                Log.e("RECEIVE",username.concat(" "+message));
                                setAdapter(username, message);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        void setAdapter(String name, String message) {
            ChatModel chatModel = new ChatModel();
            chatModel.setUserName(name);
            chatModel.setMessage(message);
            listItems.add(chatModel);
            if (chatAdapter == null) {
                chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(this, listItems);
                chatroom.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
            } else {
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            chatroom.setSelection(chatAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }


        private void attemptSend() {
            String message = messageBox.getText().toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
                return;
            }
            messageBox.setText("");
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("username", "Hassan");
                obj.put("message", message);
                obj.put("id", "computer");

                mSocket.emit("chat_sample_test", obj, new Ack() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Message received by device",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                setAdapter("me", message);
                Log.e("SEND",message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.sendButton:
                    attemptSend();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mSocket.disconnect();
            mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
            mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
            mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
            mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
            mSocket.off("mobile", onMessageReceive);
        }
    }
```

My logic here is, from the html application, i will send the message to mobile and vice versa.First, I have connected with the `chat_sample_test` room. when i tried to send the message using html application, the server prints the message based on the console i have added in nodejs server. but the mobile not receiving the message. the same happening in mobile end.No error found.

**NOTE:**

when i try to send the message to mobile , i have added the id as `mobile` (mobile need to receive  the message), where as in mobile i have added id as `computer`(Computer need to receive the message)

Helps will be appreciated.

Comment: `, from the html application, i will send the message to mobile `. The html javascript cannot sent to the mobile as the mobile is a client. As the javascript is. So both can only send data to the server.

Comment: Thank you for replying. See, here , All the message send through server only. server sends the message to mobile and vice versa.

Comment: Then adapt your post as it is confusing now. Write a clear story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just now i found the answer. thank you guys who are all try to solve the issue.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000,console.log("Socket.io Hello Wolrd server started!"));
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    //console.log("Client connected!");
    socket.on('chat_sample_test', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg.id);
        console.log(msg.message);
      socket.broadcast.emit(msg.id, msg.message);//here added broadcast obj.So now working fine.
    })
});
```